# Reading specifically formatted string

Tags: c, linux, string, windows, scanf

I'm attempting to read a file containing lines of strings in the following format:

```
"string";"string";"string";"string";"string"
```

How do i read them each using functions compatible on windows and linux?

Length of each string is unknown.

i have attempted to use fscanf like this:

```
fscanf(fp, "\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\"\n");
```

But the first string picked up the whole line.

Comment: That is a variant of the common [Comma-Separated Values (or CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file format. And it only *seems* like it's easy to parse. For example, if one of the strings contains spaces then your `fscanf` call won't work. I really recommend you try to find an existing library that will parse the file properly, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Can you have embedded quotes or semicolons? as in `"first";"semi;colon";"foo"bar";"fourth"`

Comment: @pmg The file is expected to be absolutely perfect it always should contain the above stated format. If anything else is read error should be returned.

Comment: @Dejan pmg's point is that the "above stated format" is not precise enough to write a simple parser for. You must know the full space of allowed inputs, and embedded quotes or punctuation is certainly typically okay for something called "a string".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not allowed to use external libraries, i'm either supposed to find a way with fscanf or some other function for reading, or parse it myself.

Comment: Then you need to know *exactly* what can be in a "string"? Spaces? Semicolons? Embedded double-quotes? "Escape" sequences?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude everything that's in string exempting " and ;

Comment: So white-space (space, tabs, possibly newlines) are valid inside the strings?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Anything is valid inside the strings

Comment: If there can be white-space, you have to remember that `scanf` (and family) format `"%s"` reads *space delimited* strings. And if there can be embedded newlines you can't really use `fgets` to read full lines and then split at semicolon using `strtok` (which is otherwise a common way to handle it). Your only solution, it seems, is to read *character by character* with a statefull parser.

Comment: And for future question, you really should include all these details in the question itself. We shouldn't have to drag it out of you in comments like this.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use `fscanf`, you could use a format string like this :

```
fscanf(fp, "\"%[^\"]\";\"%[^\"]\";\"%[^\"]\";\"%[^\"]\";\"%[^\"]\"\n", ...);
```

For more details, read up on the *[set]* conversion specifier in the reference docs for [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Note that this will *not* work with embedded `'"'` characters in the strings.

This also leaves no flexibility (like additional whitespace around the semicolons, optional quotes, etc.).

In case those limitations are problematic for you, you'll want a more intelligent parser ([libcsv](https://github.com/rgamble/libcsv) comes to mind eg.). Also ref. [pmg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54670361/822669) for how to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

here's some pseudo-code for you

```
loop
    getchar; if not a quote exit with error
    loop
        getchar; mind EOF
        if not a quote, add to string
        if a quote exit inner loop
    use string
    getchar; if not semicolon exit with error unless EOF
```